# How to stub class instantiated inside tested class in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have problem stubbing external api, following is the example

```
require 'rspec'
require 'google/apis/storage_v1'

module Google
  class Storage
    def upload file
      puts '#' * 90
      puts "File #{file} is uploaded to google cloud"
    end
  end
end

class UploadWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    Google::Storage.new.upload 'test.txt'
  end
end


RSpec.describe UploadWorker do

  it 'uploads to google cloud' do
    google_cloud_instance = double(Google::Storage, insert_object: nil)
    expect(google_cloud_instance).to receive(:upload)
    worker = UploadWorker.new
    worker.perform
  end
end
```

I'm trying to stub Google::Storage class. This class is instantiated inside the object being tested. How can I verify the message expectation on this instance?

When I run above example, I get following output, and it seems logical, my double is not used by tested object

```
(Double Google::Storage).upload(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
```

I'm new to Rspec and having hard time with this, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Where would `insert_object` even be called? Currently it appears you are calling `Google::Storage#upload`?

Comment: Thanks for highlighting #upload, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reaching for DI is always a good idea (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51401376/299774) but there are sometimes reasons you can't so it, so here's another way to stub it without changing the "production" code.

## 1. `expect_any_instance_of`

```
it 'uploads to google cloud' do
  expect_any_instance_of(Google::Storage).to receive(:insert_object)
  worker = UploadWorker.new
  worker.perform
end
```

In case you just want to test that the method calls the method on any such objects.

## 2. bit more elaborated setup

In case you want to control or set up more expectations, you can do this

```
  it 'uploads to google cloud' do
    the_double = instance_double(Google::Storage)
    expect(Google::Storage).to receive(:new).and_return(the_double)
       # + optional `.with` in case you wanna assert stuff passed to the constructor
    expect(the_double).to receive(:insert_object)
    worker = UploadWorker.new
    worker.perform
  end
```

Again - Dependency Injection is clearer, and you should aim for it. This is presented as another possibility.

Comment: Depending on what you need. `allow` is fine too. But you need `expect` if you want to verify the arguments passed there.

Comment: As docs recomends "though in general we
discourage its use for a number of reasons". `expect_any_instance_of` it should be avoided as much as possible (https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-8/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance)

Answer (score 3):

I would consider reaching for dependency injection, such as:

```
class UploadWorker
  def initialize(dependencies = {})
    @storage = dependencies.fetch(:storage) { Google::Storage }
  end

  def perform
    @storage.new.upload 'test.txt'
  end
end
```

Then in the spec you can inject a double:

```
storage = double
expect(storage).to receive(...) # expection
worker = UploadWorker.new(storage: storage)
worker.perform
```

If using the initializer is not an option then you could use getter/setter method to inject the dependency:

```
def storage=(new_storage)
  @storage = new_storage
end

def storage
  @storage ||=  Google::Storage
end
```

and in the specs:

```
storage = double
worker.storage = storage
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, UploadWorker is sidekiq worker and I guess we can't pass any parameters in initialize method

Comment: It depends if sidekiq also uses the initialize method and passes anything to it, you could call `super()` in `#initialize` and see if it still works.

Comment: it doesn't work, we can't pass parameters in initialize method of the workers. So is there any other way to stub this or make it work?

Comment: The other option would be to use getter/setter methods to inject the dependency.